# Drupal 7. Translate URLs

Tags: url, drupal-7, translate

How can I translate the urls  ex.  somesite.com/user to somesite.com/usario

in addition I would need to translate somesite.com/user/password  somesite.com/user/register

Can I manually change the urls?

The site is built using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can add aliases.  Make sure the core module named "Path" is enable,d then you can go to admin/config/search/path to view all aliases.  There's a link to add a new alias as well.

Aliases will give you an alternate path.  It is now node/1 can get changed to 'something-else'.  node/1 will still work, but the alias will present node/1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, URL aliases are for customizing. So you could go ahead and start translating for yourself every single URL of your site, or you can update regularly module languages as they are written, and the URL will be translated automagically, as well as the the interfaces of the modules. If your only concern is the translation (not customization), then that's what I advise to do.
This is hard and repetitive unless you have a module that does it for you: [check this out](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update).

So what this does is keep an eye on the updates and fetch the translations as they are added. How cool is that? ;)

NB: translations are not just the words, they also involve things like date format (which differs from one language another) and that's what makes this module so important.